# Sql query - search a varchar containing a wildcard character

Tags: sql

If I execute this query:

```
select * from product where product_name like '%';
```

it gets all the products and that's expected.

But I want to get the products where the name contains the wildcard character '%'.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ESCAPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

> match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]
>
> **Is a character that is put in front of a wildcard character to indicate that the wildcard should be interpreted as a regular
>   character and not as a wildcard.** escape_character is a character
>   expression that has no default and must evaluate to only one
>   character.

```
select *  
from product  
where product_name like '%|%%'  ESCAPE '|';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406799)**</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

Presuming that you're using SQL-Server (thought you've mentioned it somewhere):

You have to escape the wildcard character `%` with brackets:

```
select *  from product  where product_name like '%[%]%';
```

[**Demo**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406802/percentage-in-where)

Side-note: you have to do the same if you want to search underscores:

```
select *  from product  where product_name like '%[_]%';
```

because this means *any single character*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'll try it :)

Comment: No rows are selected :(

Comment: @neila: then there are no poducts which name contains a `%`. Have you noticed that i have edited my answer. In the first version i have used `where product_name like '[%]'` that only finds products which name is `%`

Comment: You should add that searching wildcards in range `[]` is `SQL Server` specific. OP does not tell which RDBMS he uses

Answer (score 3):

While both Tim's and lad2025's answers are correct, a third option on SQL Server is to use CHARINDEX:

```
select *
from product where charindex('%', product_name) > 0
```

CHARINDEX does not use special characters for pattern matching, so you can use the % character in the search. However, if you use PATINDEX, it will behave similar to `LIKE`.

Comment: You should add that `CHARINDEX` is SQL Server specific. For Oracle/MySQL OP should use `INSTR` 

Answer (score 0):

If the language you are looking for is Oracle (which it most seems like in your case), then

```
SELECT *  FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\';
```

should work.